# command to find and delete files containing $ in filename

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have to delete 60 days older files using find command. I am using following command to delete:

```
find /etc/tertiary/files/ -type f -name "CDT42D.FDI20T$*.txt" -mtime +60 -print \
| awk -F"/" '{print $NF}' \
| xargs -n 50 rm
```

but it is failing as the file name has '$' , please suggest what changes needs to be done to above command in order to delete files having special character($) in their names.

Comment: Use single quotes with -name and not double quotes to avoid any variable expansion attempts.

Comment: Use single quotes for `-name` argument and you don't need to pipe the output to `awk` and `xargs`.  Find command has `-delete` flag to delete the entry found `find /etc/tertiary/files/ -type f -name 'CDT42D.FDI20T$*.txt' -mtime +60 -delete` should work

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delete all files that have $ in their names you can use :

```sh
rm *$*
```

Comment: As per the OP's description, **60 days older** files having `$` in their name need to be deleted...